# Java 1.6 has runtime errors reading a file when 1.7 is fine

Tags: java, java-6

i have been working on an assignment on my own PC using JDK v1.7, and i have to submit my assignment on my uni's Unix computer with java version 1.6.

All of my code executes fine on my machine, and when i SSH into my uni's computer and transfer my code across, it compiles fine, too. however, when I go to run it, i receive a

```
NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

about 1000-1200 characters into the .xml file I need to read (the file is much longer than this).

the offending method is

```
private CDAlbum CDread(Scanner inLine) {
    String tempTitle = "Unknown CD";
    String tempGenre = "Unknown Genre";
    String tempArtist = "Unknown Artist";
    ArrayList<String> tempTracks = new ArrayList<String>();

    do {
        lineBuffer = inLine.nextLine();
        if (lineBuffer.equals("<Title>")) {
            tempTitle = inLine.nextLine();
            System.out.println("reading in a CD, just read title: " + tempTitle);
        } else if (lineBuffer.equals("<Genre>")) {
            tempGenre = inLine.nextLine();
        } else if (lineBuffer.equals("<Artist>")) {
            tempArtist = inLine.nextLine();
            //System.out.println("Which has artist: " + tempArtist);
        } else if (lineBuffer.equals("<Tracks>")) {
            //populate tracks array
            lineBuffer = inLine.nextLine();
            while (!(lineBuffer.equals("</Tracks>"))) {
                tempTracks.add(lineBuffer);
                //System.out.println("Read track: " + lineBuffer);
                lineBuffer = inLine.nextLine();
            }
        }
    } while (!(lineBuffer.equals("</CD>")));
    System.out.println(tempTracks);
    CDAlbum tempdisc = new CDAlbum(tempTitle, tempGenre, tempArtist, tempTracks);
    return tempdisc;
}
```

with the error occurring at

```
lineBuffer = inLine.nextLine();
```

I'm a bit out of my debugging depth here, and any suggestions as to what could be causing this are welcome.

screenshot of console output: http://puu.sh/YXKN

entire source code (just in case, and because it's easy to do with dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zz8vdzqgw296s3d/v_cfW5svHG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer not required any more - turns out i was mistaken, and the assignment is being marked on a windows 7 machine running java 1.7.